# Selecting the correct first child

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to get my css to select the 'correct' first div but can't seem to isolate it. Here's my (stripped back, but correct) html:

```
<div id="page_container">
    <div></div> // this div has content, but no id or class
    <div class="holder"></div> // this div has content
    <div class="section"></div> // <<<< this is the div I want to select; the first div with the class 'section'
    <div class="section"></div> // I don't want to select other 'section's
    <div class="section"></div>
    <div class="section"></div>
</div>
```

CSS-wise, so far I have tried...

```
#page_container > div > .section:first-child {
    ...rules here
}

#page_container > div:first-child(.section) { // is this even valid?
    ...rules here
}

#page_container > div > div > .section:first-child {
    ...rules here
}
```

...without luck.

I may be experiencing a brain-fart, but how would I select just the first div with a class of 'section'?

Any help, much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried `#page_container > div.section:first-child`?

Comment: unfortunately there's no `:first-child-of-class` selector

Comment: There's a quite elaborate answer on a same kind of question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8539107/4278038

Comment: you can try this `#page_container > :not(.section) + .section {`

Comment: @McVenco I have to say, if I had encountered that answer in my searching I, 1) wouldn't have known it was answering my question, and 2) wouldn't have understood it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```css
#page_container .section{
  background: green;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

#page_container .section ~ .section {
    background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="page_container">
    <div>this div has content, but no id or class</div>
    <div class="holder">this div has content</div>
    <div class="section">this is the div I want to select; the first div with the class 'section'</div>
    <div class="section">I don't want to select other 'section's</div>
    <div class="section"></div>
    <div class="section"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works! Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @moosefetcher, Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You could use `+` Combinator.

> **Adjacent sibling combinator**
>
> The + combinator selects adjacent siblings. This means that the second element directly follows the first, and both share the same parent.
>
> **Syntax**: A + B
>
> **Example**: h2 + p will match all `<p>` elements that directly follow an `<h2>`.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Example:

```css
#page_container > .holder + .section {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="page_container">
    <div>this div has content, but no id or class</div> 
    <div class="holder">this div has content</div> 
    <div class="section">this is the div I want to select; the first div with the class 'section'</div>
    <div class="section">I don't want to select other 'section's</div>  
    <div class="section"></div>
    <div class="section"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I maybe should have said that the actual page html is generated dynamically (angular.js), so I can't always guarantee that the 'holder' div will be present. Therefore I really need the css to focus on the 'section' class.

Comment: you are most welcome